# Can I default the action name to the controller value in a route in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and areas...I'd like to have a routing structure that's basically `{area}/{controller}/{id}`, and make the action equal to the `{controller}` value.  I'd like to do this to emulate the action controller pattern described [here](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-asp-net-mvc-actioncontroller-ndash-the-controllerless-action-or-actionless-controller/), but using MVC3 out of the box.

Basically, it would be great if this works (but it doesn't):

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Request_Default",
                "Request/{controller}/{id}",
                new { action = "{controller}", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write own `Route` that will do it or simply put something like this in `global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState()
{
    var handler = Context.Handler as MvcHandler;

    if (handler == null)
        return;

    var routeData = handler.RequestContext.RouteData;

    var action = routeData.Values["action"];
    if (action == null)
        routeData.Values["action"] = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
}
```

and map route like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Request_Default",
    "Request/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```